# How to display separate orders in an SMS using twilio & rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sms, twilio

I have a food ordering web app that sends food orders directly to my delivery drivers. I want to display a list of each meal ordered as well as the quantity. I'm having trouble displaying this correctly in SMS form.

In my app, the user can chooses meals which are then added to the cart as a cart_item. Once the user pays for the cart, a charge is created.

Here is the code:

**charges_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @charge = Charge.new(charge_params)

  @amount = @cart.total_price  
  @phone = @charge.phone
  @location = @charge.address
  @meal_order = @cart.meal_order

  begin 
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => @charge.email,
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe Customer',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

    # TWILIO 
    send_text_message(@phone, @meal_order, @location, @amount)

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
  end

  @cart.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    if @charge.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Charge was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @charge }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @charge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def send_text_message(customer_phone, meal_order, location, amount)
  number_to_send_to = "xxx-xxx-xxx"

  account_sid =         ENV["account_sid"]
  auth_token =          ENV["auth_token"]
  twilio_phone_number = ENV["twilio_phone_number"]

  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

  @client.account.messages.create(
    :from => "#{twilio_phone_number}",
    :to => number_to_send_to,
    :body => "New meal order! 
              Customer Phone number: #{customer_phone}.   
              Meal Order: #{meal_order}.     
              Location: #{location}    
              Total: $#{amount / 100}"    
  )
end
```

**cart.rb**

```
def meal_order
  cart_items.to_a do |item|
    item.meal.name
    item.quantity
  end
end
```

An example SMS response that I get will look like this:

> New Meal Order!
>   Customer Phone Number: xxx-xxx-xxxx
>   Meal Order:
>   CartItemid: 26, meal_id: 6, cart_id: 16, created_at: "2014-12-06 12:03:11", updated_at: "2013-12-06 12:04:11", quantity: 2,
>   CartItemid: 27, meal_id: 3, cart_id: 16, created_at: "2014-12-06 12:03:11", updated_at: "2013-12-06 12:04:11", quantity: 3. 
>   Location: 6200 Customer Street San Diego CA
>   Total: $45

I'd prefer for it to neatly print out the names of the meals as well as the quantity and not print it out like it has. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking mainly good there. I think the issue is that your `Cart#meal_order` method isn't doing what you expect. I'm not sure that `to_a` does anything with a block when it is passed. So `meal_order` is just returning `cart_items` which, when printed, is outputting the attributes of your `cart_items`.

Try something like this instead:

```
def meal_order
  item_names = cart_items.map do |item|
    "#{item.meal.name} - #{item.quantity}"
  end
  item_names.to_sentence
end
```

This way, we use map to turn the cart items into strings containing the name and quantity. Since you're using Rails, you can then use [`to_sentence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence) on the array to convert the array to a comma separated sentence with the last two elements separated by "and".

Let me know if that helps at all!

Comment: You sir are awesome!! This is why I should focus on Ruby before I hack away at Rails. Thank you! :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of the app.